# How to make animation() endless

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have an element which should be animated all the time.
The animated element has such CSS properties:

```
#world {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background :red;
}
```

I can only move the element to a particular way, like this:

```
$('#world').animate({right: "2000px", easing: "linear"}, 2000);
```

But this will just animated for 2000px my element has an endless width.

**UPDATE:**

ALL 7.5 Sec. `#world` become bigger.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/csxLeeak/)**

Comment: Do you also have an endless monitor? How much did it cost?

Comment: The speed is 1000px/sec, multiply the ratio by 7*24*60*60 to animate for a week!

Comment: @HashemQolami my script will not run a week

Comment: @Selfproblemmade So the width won't be endless (?) For an endless width you have to animate the element forever!

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle with the large element in and what you have so far. We are all coming up with suggestions in which you are dismissing. Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/csxLeeak/ here it tooks a long time but now im finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a recursive function:

```
var anim;

anim = function(times) {
  $('#world').animate({
    right: 2000 * times
  }, 2000, 'linear');
  return anim(times + 1);
};

anim(1)
```

This will continue to move `#world` to the right, 1 pixel per millisecond.

With a step callback:

```
var anim, my_step_callback;

my_step_callback = function() {
  return $('body').append("<p>Hello</p>");
};

anim = function(times) {
  $('#world').animate({
    right: 2000 * times
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: my_step_callback
  });
  return anim(times + 1);
};
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use right: 100%?

Assuming im reading your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the `right`a value to the width of the element

```
var width = $('#world').width();

$('#world').animate({right: width, easing: "linear"}, 2000);
```

You could also increment the value of `right` as follows

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/meqk662p/

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function () {
  ++counter;
}, 100);


$('#world').animate({right: counter+"px", easing: "linear"}, 2000);
```

The above example would be infinite

Comment: yeah i tried this but it doesnt work, i forget a important information in my question: see update

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like this, Where the function calls itself over and over again each time the animation ends.

```
function moveMe() { 
     $('#world').animate({width: '+=100px', easing: "linear"}, 2000, moveMe); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try increment the right and call in the callback the same function

```
var world_right = 2000;
function endlessWorldStep(){

       $('#world')
           .animate({right: world_right + "px", easing: "linear"}, 2000, endlessWorldStep);
        world_right = world_right + 100;
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but this wont work too, it stops and go on every time. should be fluent

Comment: you will get a initial value (2000px in example) and when it's finish you will call again the method after the `world_right` already incremented `world_right = world_right + 100`, the call will be done on finish of last animate.... in part `..., 2000, endlessWorldStep);`